# Can I use same dialog in SWT to load file or folder path?

Tags: java, dialog, swt

I need to load path of the user selected folder / file, But there is either folder or file dialog, but i need file/ folder in same dialog.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is no, you can't use the same dialog for file or folders.

You can only use `DirectoryDialog` for selecting a directory and `FileDialog` for selecting a file.

Comment: I need both in one dialog

Comment: Hi, were you able to achieve this  ?